# DynamoDB : Unable to recreate a table after deleting the one with the same name

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I had a table named abc_foobar in DynamoDB. 
I dropped the table using RazorSQL's DynamoDB interface. I log into the AWS console and when I query I don't see the table. However when I try to recreate the table (a table with the same name and same partition key) using the AWS console, I get an error on the form which says that something is "Required" in the form field named "Table Name". I made sure the previous table doesn't exist. Whats going on? I can create a table with any other name but not the same name that was of the earlier table. 
Please see the attachment.

Comment: No attachment seen.  Does this work again after waiting some period of time?

Comment: Probably, delete was in progress when you tried to recreate the table. If the table status is DELETING, it may throw an error. Use describe table command to check the current status of the table before creating a new table with the same name.